# Controlling Google Assitant compatible devices via HTTP/MQTT

Tags: alexa, hardware, communication, google-assistant

I would like to control an IoT device that is compatible with Google Assistant/Alexa/Smart Life locally within my network using some open API over HTTP/MQTT. Is this even possible or is the only way to go via the APIs of these companies?

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic answer to this. Each device will be different, each with their own API which may or may not include a form of local control.

Google/Amazon/etc. do not provide a generic API you can call to control devices paired with their infrastructure. They tend to work the other way round, the vendors have to implement an API that Google/Amazon call (with the right oAuth token) to trigger things to happen.